# Adjacency Lists and average time complexity for binary search (2 separate questions)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, binary-search-tree, adjacency-list

Is the average time complexity for a successful binary search in a sorted array and in a binary search tree the same, ***O(log (n))***?

Also, are the worst-case time complexity the same for both, ***O(n)***?

---

When drawing an adjacency list for a graph, does the order of this matter? For example, would it be wrong to change this:

[image]

To this (notice in the first row how the 2 and 3 are switched):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst and average for searching in a sorted array is O(Log n). And that's because if the array is sorted, you will make at most O(Log n) jumps to conclude that the element does not exist.

In a BST, the worst and average are O(n) and O(Log n) respectively with worst case happening when the tree is completely skewed and thus behaving like a linked list.

---

Their order may matter in some execution you may perform (like DFS returning different path to another node) but both adjacency list representations are totally valid.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes much more sense. I remember that is how my professor explained the run-times but it has been a while so my memory has failed me. I tried googling it and kept getting mixed results which I knew were off. Thank you!